# Can you expand the same formula in different branches in the method of analytic tableaux?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

I need to prove $\vdash_{TA} (p \land q) \lor (p \land r) \rightarrow p \land (q \lor r)$

For that, I did such:

[image]

But I've expanded $Fp \land (q \lor r)$ twice in different branches though, is this allowed?

Comment: Correct; in Tableaux for pro logic we do not re-use formulas, but if a formula has not been used yet and the tableaux branches, when we want to use it we have to use it in every open branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is that allowed, but it is in fact *mandated*! As long as we still have one or more open branches, we need to explore the possible ways in which the statements that occur in that branch can have the truth-value as assigned, i.e. we need to keep applying decomposition rules until either we get all closed branches, or until there is nothing left to decompose.

In your case, once you have reached the $Tr$ in the right branch, that branch is still open, but the $FP\land (Q \lor R)$ has not yet been decomposed in that branch. And since there is nothing else to do, you *have to* decompose it at that point.